# Syntax in Java - Using Classes withing Tags

Tags: java, selenium

I'm learning java and selenium and some time I could see Class names enclosed within a tag. I couldn't understand what it means.

```
 Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
   .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
   .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
   .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);


WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() {
 public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
   return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
 }
```

Could any one explain it?

Comment: Those are parameterized types. Generics is the keyword you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Its called Generics. Check this Wikipedia article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java